# What is the name of term for series of studies for the same patient?

Tags: terminology

If we have a series of assessment of lesion for some patient, how is it called in English? Looks like the study term is used for every single assessment(visit). How the whole series is called?

Comment: Are you asking about a series of visits (at a bed in the hospital) or a series of tests? Does a patient comes from home and visits a doctor in the office, or a doctor visits a patient in the hospital room?

Comment: a series of tests in the hospital lab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/work-up):

> **Workup** is a complete medical study of a patient, including a thorough examination, laboratory tests, a survey of the patient's case
>   history, etc.

On [eMedicine](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/175667-workup#showall) you can see an example of a workup for gallstones.